# Is there evidence of suppression of the frontal cortex during herding behavior?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience

Phenomena such as large-scale stock market sell-offs and financial panic in general are often explained in terms of herding behaviors.

At how primitive of a level does one actually "follow the herd"?  In other words, does this behavior elicit a strong response at the brainstem level (particularly in the tectum, i.e., the colliculi) at some cost to frontal cortical processing?

Obviously, it's a difficult task to run an EEG or have a subject in for an MRI during a real panic, so results based on simulations are certainly acceptable.

Comment: If someone more steeped in this area has a better name for the latter tag, please change the name to something else (just retag and this tag will be purged)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not a complete answer to your question.

There have been a few studies on this relationship.

[This article from the Journal of Neuroscience](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/31/33/11934.full) "Downregulation of the Posterior Medial Frontal Cortex Prevents Social Conformity" (Klucharev et al. 2011) approach the research (from their abstract):

> Here we demonstrate that the transient downregulation of the posterior medial frontal cortex by theta-burst transcranial magnetic stimulation reduces conformity, as indicated by reduced conformal adjustments in line with group opinion.

[This article may also be of interest](http://pure.au.dk/portal/files/45260302/Raafat2009.pdf)

Comment: I totally spaced on selecting this as the answer, thanks.

Comment: @ChuckSherrington no problems at all, I do that all the time.